# Google Spreadsheet batch update very slow

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, gdata-api, google-sheets-api

I'm updating a google spreadsheet and it takes about 30 seconds to update 100 cells.
I'm using the code described in the answer in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714074/batch-update-to-spreadsheet-with-google-gdata-api-using-2-legged-oauth-open-id)
Is this normal? This just seem to be horribly slow and nearly impossible to work with. Are there any options out there to speed up this process?

Comment: Fast batch update answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug

Comment: Small sheets are faster: The speed of the write is impacted by the size of the sheet. Even if you only change one cell in the sheet, large sheets are slower. The size of the overall speadsheet has little impact, but sheet size matters.

Comment: Please put the answer in the answer box, and the question in the question box, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in the provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug)
I changed:

```
  private CellEntry createUpdateOperation(URL cellFeedUrl, int row, int col, String value) throws ServiceException, IOException {
    String batchId = "R" + row + "C" + col;
    URL entryUrl = new URL(cellFeedUrl.toString() + "/" + batchId);
    CellEntry entry = this.service.getEntry(entryUrl, CellEntry.class);
    entry.changeInputValueLocal(value);
    BatchUtils.setBatchId(entry, batchId);
    BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(entry, BatchOperationType.UPDATE);
    return entry;
  }
```

into:

```
  private CellEntry createUpdateOperation(URL cellFeedUrl, int row, int col, String value) throws ServiceException, IOException {
    String batchId = "R" + row + "C" + col;
    CellEntry batchEntry = new CellEntry(row, col, value);
    batchEntry.setId(String.format("%s/%s", cellFeedUrl.toString(), batchId));
    BatchUtils.setBatchId(batchEntry, batchId);
    BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(batchEntry, BatchOperationType.UPDATE);
    return batchEntry;
  }
```

300 cells edited in +/-20 seconds now so it's better...

Comment: The question is: why they are so slow? How can an API be so slow?