# Google Spreadsheet Batch Insert from android

Tags: android, google-sheets

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714074/batch-update-to-spreadsheet-with-google-gdata-api-using-2-legged-oauth-open-id) post to be extremely helpful. I've also been *trying* to make use of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/batch), but I can't seem to combine the two (plus other sources) to do a batch insert.

The problem seems to revolve around the setting of the `BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(...)`. If I set it to `UPDATE` the batch process returns a 400 error ""Missing entry id" and if I set it to `INSERT` or don't set it, I get a 501 "Insert not supported on batch."

Is insert *really* not support for batch operations? I think it much more likely that I'm doing something wrong.

I present to you the code:

```
    String scope = "oauth2:https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";

    String accountName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(GDriveActivity.this, accountName, scope, null);

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("v1");
    service.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    String id = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/tnkZhv6iUaHx9-BVsqbWEKg";
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);

    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {

        if (spreadsheet.getId().equals(id)) {
            WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
            List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
            WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

            URL cellFeedUrl = worksheet.getCellFeedUrl();
            CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

            CellFeed batchRequest = new CellFeed();

            // this will go in a loop, later
            addEntryToBatch(batchRequest, 1, 1, "Some text", "A");
            addEntryToBatch(batchRequest, 1, 2, "More text", "B");

            Link batchLink = cellFeed.getLink(Link.Rel.FEED_BATCH, Link.Type.ATOM);
            service.setHeader("If-Match", "*"); // btw, not sure what this does. Bonus if you can clue me in.
            URL url = new URL(batchLink.getHref());
            CellFeed batchResponse = service.batch(url, batchRequest);
            service.setHeader("If-Match", null); // turns off the thing above.
            for (CellEntry entry : batchResponse.getEntries()) {
                if (!BatchUtils.isSuccess(entry)) {

                    // always end up here :(
                    BatchStatus status = BatchUtils.getBatchStatus(entry);
                    int code = status.getCode(); // 400 or 501
                    String reason = status.getReason(); // "Missing entry id" or "Insert not supported on batch."
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    //-----------

    private void addEntryToBatch(CellFeed batchRequest, int row, int col, String entryText, String id) {

        if (entryText != null) {
            CellEntry entry = new CellEntry(row, col, entryText);
            BatchUtils.setBatchId(entry, id);

            // BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(entry, BatchOperationType.INSERT); // <-- returns 501
            // BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(entry, BatchOperationType.UPDATE); // <-- returns 400
            // Ommiting the OperationType returns 501

            batchRequest.getEntries().add(entry);
        }
    }
```

Also *anything* else weird or funky about my code...PLEASE comment and critique. I'm very new to this and this is basically some Frankenstein code from several sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

As far as I can determine it is NOT possible to do a bulk insert. Even if you are working with a blank worksheet that has only empty cells, you **must** first retrieve those blank cells and then **update** them.

I'll point again to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714074/batch-update-to-spreadsheet-with-google-gdata-api-using-2-legged-oauth-open-id), that I basically recycled in order to do my "Insert" (which, again, was really an update of blank cells).

Happy to be wrong. If you've got a better solution, please post.